# Wordpress or Drupal: Plugin for sub threads

Tags: wordpress, drupal, plugins

I'm looking for a wordpress OR drupal plugin with which the users of my site can create a sub discussion to an article by themselves and invite other users to join. This subdiscussion should be invisible to not invited Users. Is there anything similar? Or could I do this some other way?

I didn't decide for wordpress or drupal by now, so which ever cms can do this will be it.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I doubt you'll find an out-of-the-box solution for either WordPress or Drupal that will do exactly what you're looking for. At the least, I suspect you'd need to do some customization, but you'd probably actually need write something from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of such a module for Drupal but if you'll go for the custom module route here's some pointers to how it could be implemented:

- Create a content type called Subarticle, enable comments and add a Node reference field to it. Allow your users to create nodes of that type.
- For the widget of the node reference, use the [Node Reference URL Widget](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) module which will create a link on each Article, something like Create a Subarticle, automatically making the new subarticle point to the article.
- For display, views could be used with a node argument on the node reference field.
- For invites and visibility, check out [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og). When a new subarticle is saved you'll have to programmatically create a new organic group, make the current user the owner and add the subarticle to that group. With an organic group he can then invite users.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes, indeed, with a bunch of plugins, especially thanks to "Views" and "OG" I managed to get at least quite close to what I needed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/features/embed-vanilla), that can be easily integrated wtih Drupal or Wordpress (or anything). Check out this [podcast](http://screenr.com/M4l) to see how easy it is to plug into WP. There are plugins for Vanilla that provide the private thread functionality you are looking for.